# R- openfn results in permission denied on windows

Tags: r, windows, permissions

I am attempting to reproduce the output from the given code below.

```
snpgdsBED2GDS(gwas.fn$bed, gwas.fn$fam, gwas.fn$bim, gwas.fn$gds)
genofile <- openfn.gds(gwas.fn$gds, readonly = FALSE)
```

The resulting output of the commands above are:

```
    Error in file(filename, "wb") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(filename, "wb") :
      cannot open file:\2020\STUDIO\GWAS/GWAStutorial.gds': Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you have the file open with another program?

Comment: No, The file is create with snpgdsBED2GDS ...and then it will be read with genofile <- openfn.gds(gwas.fn$gds, readonly = FALSE)

Comment: We can't help without even knowing what package you are using. Maybe contact the maintainer of that package to file a bug report?